# Fixed background with centered content

Tags: html, css

I want to center all the content of a website with a fullscreen background even when resized with CTRL + scroll mouse button on windows.

Website exemple : http://www.benzinga.com/

Three quarter of the website are like that anyway. (Facebook, Twitter,  StackOverflow, ...)

Example of what I mean :

[image: ( Click for the Image)]

If you press CTRL and use the scroll button on your mouse, you will see that the background of the header stays full screen, but the content stays centered.

Is it possible to do that only with HTML and CSS?

Can you show me how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the first line:

```
body{
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left:240px;
padding-right: 240px;
}
```

the value of padding you can set as you needed.
[my demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGbRxB)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I meant. I found the solution by myself. Thank you everyone.

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="pageSize" >
            <p class="left">header</p>  
            <p class="right">header</p>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
```

```
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        header {
            background: #5AFFE5;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100px;
        }



        .pageSize {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .left{
            float: left;
            line-height: 0em;
        }

        .right{
            float: right;
            line-height: 0em;
        }

        div:before, div:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
        }

        div:after {
            clear: both;
        } 

    </style>
```